# Не запускается служба mysql57

Tags: mysql

Запускаю службу через командную строку с правами администратора. Вот что я получаю:

```
C:\Windows\system32>net start mysql57
Служба "MySQL57" запускается..
Не удалось запустить службу "MySQL57".

Служба не сообщает об ошибке.

Для вызова дополнительной справки наберите NET HELPMSG 3534.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В журнале ошибка:

> Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist.

Не понимаю откуда она взялась, ведь я ничего не делал.

Comment: Попробуйте опять запустить сервер, затем посмотрите, что *MySql57* пишет в журнал. Для этого зайдите в `Панель управления → Администрирование → Просмотр событий`, затем поищите (не знаю, куда именно пишет MySQL-сервер) записи с красным восклицательным знаком и чем-то похожим на `mysql` в столбце «Источник». Поиск облегчает то, что все записи по умолчанию отсортированы от самых последних до самых старых.

Comment: @Arhad посмотрел, вылезло 3 предуприждения и 2 ошибки: 1.Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it. 2. Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist. Не понимаю откуда они взялись, ведь я ничего не делал.

Comment: По-поводу первой ошибки: я запустил mysql_upgrade - ошибка не пропала.